# MySQL master slave replica interrupts after service restart or reboot

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

I've been using the master slave replica to keep a mySQL database and its disaster recovery perfectly aligned.

I noticed that unfortunately every time the mySQL service restarts, or one of the server is rebooted, the replica stops to work and I need to reactivate it manually.

Maybe this behavior is normal and acceptable in some kind of scenario, but in a real working environment this is not reliable and sustainable.

I need to understand if there is any option to avoid this interruption, or some way to automatize the restart. When I launch the "show master status" command, I noticed that the master log file ("file" column) is incremental, but the master log position ("position" column) is not. Is there any way to control these parameters? Or is there any other reliable process more than master slave replica, in a mySQL environment?

Many thanks in advance, Kind regards

P.S. I'm aware there are similar questions on the website, but this topic it's still unclear to me, apologies.

Comment: Including `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` / `SHOW REPLICA STATUS` as the mode detailed version of "replica stops" would help. As would the server version and configuration used. You can edit the question to include this. Check you have a different [server_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_id) on master and replica..

Comment: anything in the error log?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your reply. There is no actually error, simply the replica stops to work. This is the output:

Slave SQL not running on [ServerName] Error number: 0 Error message: (empty)

Comment: Hi Dan, the server version is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and MySQL version is 8.0.27 on both master and slave.
After the replica stops to work, the Slave_IO_State becomes empty, Master_Log_File still  refers to the old log file. There is no error message, just an empty field.

After all I don't understand yet whether master-slave replica is supposed to reconnect automatically after a restart or not... I mean, is this the "normal" behaviour (in other words I'll never be able to find a solution) or something is actually wrong in my environment/configuration?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [SHOW REPLICA STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-replica-status.html), (formerly [SHOW SLAVE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-slave-status.html)), you will see a `Connect_Retry:` defaulting to 60 seconds. It should reconnect after this interval.

This `MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY` is part of the [CHANGE MASTER TO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/change-master-to.html) syntax.

Comment: Hi Danblack, thanks for your reply.
I had a look at the Connect_Retry parameter, but - as long as I could see - the reconnection would work only if the master log file and master log position didn't change.
After a server reboot or a mySQL service restart, it doesn't reconnect automatically and I always have to launch the replica manually once again. I'm afraid this is not the solution to my problem... thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it wasn’t a delayed reconnect.

It turned out that the permissions for the replication user account on each server allowing the slave to read the binlog index file on the master and vice versa were not allowing this. So they got out of step and every time the binlog index number changed which on my system is every time the MySQL service restarts or the host server reboots.

I took the lazy way out as I was only testing in a VM environment and just gave the replication user full permissions over everything on both servers and the issue was fixed. But to be more correct, the best way to do this would be to make sure that the replication user has permissions as replication client AND replication slave on both masters, or both the master and slave servers.   If that doesn’t fix it, go through the permissions until you find the one that allows each server to read and then update the binlog index on the other server.